# Python: search through values of dict for regex

Tags: python, regex

How would one search through all the values in a dictionary object? I have tried `json3[]`, `json3`, and `json3.values()` in the parentheses below with 5 question marks in them.

My current code:

```
title = "foo"
title_pattern = re.compile("(?P<title>%s)" % title, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
json3 = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(url3))
match2 = title_pattern.search(?????)      # search all values, not keys for json3
```

Output:

```
Traceback:
Line #, match2 = title_pattern.search(?????)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Comment: What `json3` looks like?

Comment: http://xkcd.com/info.0.json

Comment: What is the expected result? `True`/`False`? keys correspond to matched values? matched values?

Comment: I just want to know if there is a match to the regex in the json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use regular expression to simply check the given string is included. Use [`in` operator](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#in):

```
>>> 'foo' in 'blah blah'
False
>>> 'foo' in 'blah foo blah'
True
```

---

```
>>> url3 = 'http://xkcd.com/info.0.json'
>>> title = "foo"
>>> json3 = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(url3))
>>> any(isinstance(value, basestring) and title in value for value in json3.itervalues())
False
>>> title = "friends"
>>> any(isinstance(value, basestring) and title in value for value in json3.itervalues())
True
```

If you really need to use regular expression, escape the `title` using [`re.escape`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape); If the `title` contains a character that has special meaning in regular expression, you will get unexpected result without escaping.

```
title_pattern = re.compile("(?P<title>%s)" % re.escape(title), # <---
                           flags=re.IGNORECASE)
json3 = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(url3))
matched = any(isinstance(value, basestring) and title_pattern.search(value) for value in json3.itervalues())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
dictor = { 
    'key1': 'valX', 'key2' : 'valX1',
    'key3': 'valY', 'key4' : 'valX2',
    'key5': 'valY3', 'key6' : 'valY4'
}
matches = filter(lambda x : re.search(r'X\d', str(x[1])), dictor.items())
print matches
```

*Gives:*

```
[('key2', 'valX1'), ('key4', 'valX2')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that matches cannot *cross* values and that your data is flat (no nested dictionaries in your response that you need to check) then you can simply do this:

```
matches = [title_pattern.search(val) \
              for val in json3.values() if isinstance(val, (str, unicode))]
```

Answer (score 0):

your json seem to just have strings in its values you can then simply do:

```
map(title_pattern.search, json3.values())
```

Comment: I still get the `TypeError` from this

Comment: hmmm, there is one `int` in there, see @SeanViera answer, he got it right